# migrate axis soap webservice to spring ws - RequestPayload object values coming as null in endpoint method

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, axis, spring-ws

Working with an old `wsdl file` generated with `AXIS` to make it work with spring ws. After doing some tweaks and all,  i could generate the java sources with the old wsdl.

Now i am trying to make a request from `soap UI` , But request values are shown as null in `endpoint` `method`. Request is coming in `backend` properly but not `values`.

WSDL file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:onl="http://online.mysite.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <onl:getSummary soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in0 xsi:type="onl:SummaryObject">
            <docid xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">doc123</docid>
            <amount xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</amount>
            <duenew xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</duenew>
            <reference xsi:type="xsd:long">?</reference>
            <sortBy xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</sortBy>
            <startDate xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</startDate>
         </in0>
      </onl:getSummary>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Soap Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:onl="http://online.mysite.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <onl:getSummary soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <in0 xsi:type="onl:SummaryObject">
            <docid xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">doc123</docid>
            <amount xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</amount>
            <duenew xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</duenew>
            <reference xsi:type="xsd:long">121212121</reference>
            <sortBy xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</sortBy>
            <startDate xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</startDate>
            <visibility xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</visibility>
         </in0>
      </onl:getSummary>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Endpoint Method:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart ="getSummary")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<EObjects> getSummary(@RequestPayload SummaryObject summaryObject) {

            System.out.println("Am done with this"+summaryObject.getDocId());
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
        EObjects objects = factory.createEObjects();
        QName qname = new QName("http://online.mysite.com", "eobjects");
        return new JAXBElement(qname, EObjects.class, objects);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSDL generated in `axis 1` is no longer been supported by `spring ws or CXF`. So that generated java classes from WSDL wont have required information that is needed for `unmarshelling` of request by `JAXB` in `spring`. Thus `request` object will come as `null`.

I have done a work around  which has 2 things to do

1. Add xml root element annotation on top of the request object class generated from WSDL.

> @XmlRootElement(name="getSomething",namespace =
>   "http://yoursite.com")

2. unmarshell the request object manually as shown below:

code

```
SoapMessage message = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(out);
            String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document d = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(strMsg)));
 Node getrequestObject = d.getElementsByTagName("yourtag").item(0);

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyRequestObject.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<SummaryObject> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new
DOMSource(getrequestObject), MyRequestObject.class);
```